# Cannonical way to create a constructable Stylsheet from an external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, native-web-component, constructable-stylesheet

I have a web component that requires to re-use external stylesheet.

Reading: https://web.dev/constructable-stylesheets/, which was recently updated, it says:

> Gotchas
>
> In earlier versions of the specification, replace() allowed @import rules and returned a Promise that resolved when these were finished loading. This feature was removed from the specification and @import rules are ignored with a warning as of Chrome 84.

MDN confirms this for both [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/replace) and [replaceSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/replaceSync#parameters):

> Note: If any of the rules passed in text are an external stylesheet imported with the @import rule, those rules will be removed, and a warning printed to the console.

All the material I read says do it like this (the depreciated method):

```
sheet.replaceSync('@import url("styles.css");');
// or
sheet.replace('@import url("styles.css");');
```

I can find multiple issues talking about removing this feature, without proposing how one is supposed to do it instead, e.g.: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/RKG8oxp22RY/m/fdFnG1rGCgAJ?pli=1

So how does one create a constructable-stylesheet from an external file?

Comment: [no signal yet from Apple](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5394843094220800) on constructable stylesheets; so they don't work in Safari

Comment: I'm using this polyfill: https://www.npmjs.com/package/construct-style-sheets-polyfill